# ASP.NET DATE type validaiton

Tags: asp.net

How i do check whether DateTime data type variable is null/empty in asp.net ?

Answer (score 2):

For a nullable `DateTime` type, you can just compare against null like this:

```
DateTime? d = null;
if (d == null)
    //do something
```

For a non-nullable `DateTime` type you can compare against the default `MinValue`:

```
DateTime d2;
if (d2 == DateTime.MinValue)
    //do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` is a value-type, so it can't be null. Is your variable actually typed as `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

It's defaultly initialized to DateTime.MinValue, so you should only check that (unless it's of type `DateTime?`):

```
if (MyDateTime==DateTime.MinValue)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if !d.HasValue
```

Hasvalue is a property present in all made-nullable types. (Basically a generic class Nullable)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a value type, therefore it cannot be null/empty. (see [this msdn entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws%28VS.71%29.aspx) for reference).

By default it will get the value of DateTime.MinValue, so you could check if it is equal to that, but it's not the best solution.

The best solution would be to create a Nullable variable of this type. The syntax is the following:

```
Nullable<DateTime> myNullableDate = ...
if(myNullableDate.HasValue) ...
```

You can also use the question mark, this way, which is a bit simpler to read:

```
DateTime? myNullableDate = ...
if(myNullableDate.HasValue) ...
```